# How to separate nested lists by element index in nextflow?

Tags: nextflow

I need to separate a channel with complex list:

The channel contains a nested list like this one: [1,['a','b'],['c','d']],[2,['a','b'],['e','f']]

How to create two new channels so that channel one contains [[1,a,c],[2,a,e]] and channel two - [[1,b,d],[2,b,f]], which basically means separating each original nested list element in two (e.g. [1,[a,b],[c,d]] becomes [1,a,c],[1,b,d]) and then combining by the second inner element ([a,b] in both cases).

So far i have managed to create a very primitive solution:

```
Channel
       .from([1,['a','b'],['c','d']],[2,['a','b'],['e','f']])
       .multiMap { 
              ch_one: tuple (it[0], it[1][0], it[2][0])
              ch_two: tuple (it[0], it[1][1], it[2][1])
              }     
       .set { to_mix }
to_mix.ch_one.subscribe {println it}
to_mix.ch_two.subscribe {println it}
```

Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're only going *to mix* the outputs anyway, I think you can just use the [`transpose`](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/operator.html#transpose) operator for this. Note that the index (zero based) of the element to be transposed can be specified using the `by` parameter. For example:

```
workflow {
       
    Channel
       .from([1,['a','b'],['c','d']],[2,['a','b'],['e','f']])
       .transpose()
       .set { transposed }

    transposed.view()
}
```

Results:

```
$ nextflow run main.nf 
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.04.1
Launching `main.nf` [naughty_agnesi] DSL2 - revision: d3d72e875e
[1, a, c]
[1, b, d]
[2, a, e]
[2, b, f]
```